# Solving Vector Multiplication (general problem)

Tags: math, vector

I am trying to solve a Mathematical equation in one of my geometric modelling problem.
Let's say if I have 2 vectors, A and B, and I have the following equation:
A x B = c (c is a scalar value).

If I know the coordinate of my vector B (7/2, 15/2); and I know the value of c, which is -4.
How can I calculate my vector A, to satisfy that equation (A X B = c) ?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/ will be better for this question

Comment: What do you mean by multiplication? The cross or dot-product?

Comment: @Jacob: Oh, good question. I saw the notation "A x B = c" and assumed it's cross product (with c being the magnitude in the direction of the unit normal), but dot product also makes sense. In that case, the problem is still underdetermined; there is no unique A.

Comment: @ShreevarsaR: Yep, I just figured multiplication was a bit too vague. And yeah it's still undetermined ; maybe he has more constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is underdetermined; there isn't a unique such A. I assume that by "multiplication" you mean the [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product).

```
A = (x,y)
B = (7/2, 15/2)
A×B = x(15/2) - y(7/2)
-4 = (15x-7y)/2
15x - 7y = -8
```

This gives a line along which points A=(x,y) can lie. Specifically, for any real number t,

```
x = -1 + 7t
y = -1 + 15t
```

gives a solution.

Comment: You're actually interpreting his answer as a dot product. Cross products take two 3-dimensional vectors and give a third 3-dimensional vector.

Comment: @Seth: Nope. When A and B are in a plane (see that his points have only two coordinates), the cross product is always along the direction normal to the plane (e.g. when A and B are in the x-y plane, A×B is always along the z-axis), so specifying the cross product as `cz` has the same information as specifying just `c`. Yeah, I should have written |A×B| instead of A×B, but this is an okay abuse of notation. BTW, the dot product A·B would be x(7/2)+y(15/2).

Comment: @Seth That's not a dot product. It's a 2D form of the cross product that maps a pair of 2D vectors to a scalar.